# Extracting specific text from select option boxes

Tags: javascript

It's possible I'm just misusing .filter() here, but I've been trying to extract a particular piece of text from javascript option boxes without much success.

In short, each of my option boxes has a bunch of info, then, in brackets, ([x] items left in stock).

I'd like to extract that [x], but I can't seem to get any sort of regular expression filtering working in jQuery - or, perhaps, I'm doing it wrong.

In short, if anyone could complete the below, I'd be very appreciative:

```
$('.productSelect').change(function() {
  selectedItem = $(this + 'option:selected').text();

  # Now grab the integer "x" inside the ([x] items left in stock) part of the text
  [ your code here]
});
```

Any help very appreciated.

Comment: This doesn't seem like a jQuery question. This is a question about regular expressions.

Comment: I'm quite familiar with regular expressions, but can't seem to extract that ([\d]+) with jQuery. I guess the question is how to extract a regex () within jQuery.

Comment: Fyi, you actual question is about pure javascript, not jquery. And you should use `var selectedItem =` instead of `selectedItem =` so you don't put your var into the global scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something along these lines:

```
$('.productSelect').change(function() {
  selectedItem = $(this + 'option:selected').text();

  # Now grab the integer "x" inside the ([x] items left in stock) part of the text
  var n = selectedItem.match(/(\()(\d+)(\))/)[2];
});
```

Of course, this expression *depends* on the fact that your data is formatted as `(number) string`

Answer (score 0):

This should get you what you need.

```
var pattern=/\[(\d+)\] items left in stock/;
var qty = pattern.exec(selectedItem)[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

So you should use the JavaScript string.match function

```
var s = "[100] items left in stock";

var p = s.match(regexp);
```